# I need a sympy function to turn into a symbol

Tags: python, sympy

So i'm working on automating FEM for ODE and i managed to create the matrix with all the unknown values that i need so i can put them on a "solve" function from sympy.
But i have one small issue: all the unknown values are a function "F".

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x')
xa = sp.Symbol('xa')
xb = sp.Symbol('xb')
N = sp.Function('N')
F = sp.Function('F')
dFdx = sp.Derivative(F(x),x)
d2Fdx2 = sp.Derivative(F(x),x,x)

sp.init_printing()

# Função aproximada

a = -5
b = 66
c = 40

x0 = 0
xf = 10
h = 2

domínio = np.arange(x0, xf + h, h)

F = a*x**2 + b*x + c

A = sp.zeros(1,len(domínio)-1)

lista_F = []
for i in range(len(domínio)-1):
    lista_F.append('F' + str(i))
    

for i in range(len(domínio)-2):
    N1 = (xb - x)/(xa - xb)
    N2 = (x - xa)/(xa - xb)
    
    integ1 = sp.integrate((d2Fdx2 + 10)*N1, (x,xa,xb))
    integ2 = sp.integrate((d2Fdx2 + 10)*N2, (x,xa,xb))
    eq1 = integ1.subs(xa, domínio[i]).subs(xb,domínio[i+1])
    eq2 = integ2.subs(xa, domínio[i]).subs(xb, domínio[i+1])
       
    A[i] += eq1
    A[i+1] = eq2
```

I could manually create another matrix with those sympy symbols. But, you know, i rather spend more effort trying to automate

Edit: xa and xb are the x values for each node. In the books, you may find "xa" as x1 and "xb" as x2

Comment: Hello, can you please include what `xa, xb` are?

Comment: I've seen the edit, *In the books, you may find "xa" as x1 and "xb" as x2*, and I still do not understand. Please, fix the code so that it can run, right now it can't as there are missing pieces and we surely don't have access to your book... What is `xa, xb`?

Answer (score 0):

Your xa and xb are the element boundaries (which you identify in your for loop). There is no need to handle them symbolically. Your quadratic function has a constant 2nd derivative (of -10) so when you add 10 to it, the result is 0 and the integration of 0 gives 0, too. I suggest doing the calculation for h=5 by hand and then checking each of the values you are expecting for the two elements of the domain. And you can clean up the code that you have by comparing it to the following:

```py
import sympy as sp

a = -5
b = 66
c = 40
x = sp.Symbol('x')
F = a*x**2 + b*x + c
d2Fdx2 = F.diff(x,2)

x0 = 0
xf = 10
h = 2
domínio = list(range(x0, xf + h, h))

A = sp.zeros(1,len(domínio)-1)
for xa, xb in zip(domínio[:-1],domínio):
    N1 = (xb - x)/h
    N2 = (x - xa)/h
    A[i] += sp.integrate((d2Fdx2 + 10)*N1, (x,xa,xb))
    A[i+1] = sp.integrate((d2Fdx2 + 10)*N2, (x,xa,xb))
```